# Pushdown Automata for number of a less than 2 times number of b

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

Suppose we want to design a pushdown automata for $L=\{x \in \{a,b \}^{*}:|x|_a<2|x|_b \}$, can anyone check whether my automata works?

we have 4 states $\{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3 \}$, three stack symbols $\{S,A,B \}$, start state $q_0$, accept state $q_3$, we have rules as following:
$q_0$ accepts nothing and push $S$ onto stack to $q_1$

$q_1$ reads $a$ and pops $B$, remain in $q_1$

$q_1$ reads $a$ and pushes $A$, remain in $q_1$

$q_1$ reads $b$ and pushes $BB$, remain in $q_1$

$q_1$ reads $b$ and pops$AA$, remain in $q_1$

$q_1$ reads $b$ and pops$A$ and pushes $B$, remain in $q_1$

$q_1$ reads nothing and pops $B$, go to $q_2$

$q_2$ reads nothing and pops $B$, remain in $q_2$

$q_2$ reads nothing and pops $S$, go to $p_3$

Comment: I think in transition rule 3 you may want to include which stack symbol should be there on stack top.

Comment: This is NPDA, the situation you mentioned will not go to the final state

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).